# Using React and trying to post data with axios- coming up empty object

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

New to react. Pretty new to coding in general. I'm just trying to post the data in drinkInfo to my database.

```
export default function CardEdit(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

const addDrinkToDatabase = () => {

  console.log("props.reduxState is" + props.reduxState)

  let drinkInfo = {
    type: props.reduxState.type,
    name:  props.reduxState.name,
    manufacturer: props.reduxState.manufacturer,
    rating: props.reduxState.rating,
    date: props.reduxState.date,
    description: props.reduxState.description,
    favorite: props.reduxState.favorite
  }

console.log("info is" + drinkInfo)

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'myurlishere',
  data: drinkInfo
};

axios.request(options)
  .then(response => {
    console.log("My response", response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("MyError:", error);
  })
}

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick = { addDrinkToDatabase } >Log Drink</button>
    </div>
)
```

I know the data is coming back right but my console.log is coming back "props.reduxState is [object Object]". I'm sure i've overlooked something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `console.log` to

```
console.log("props.reduxState is", props.reduxState)
```

Concatenating a string and object in javascript results in `[object Object]`